# Scraping data requiring scrolling down with scrapy in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scraping project I threw together with scrapy in python. Now I've come across certain data that are only loaded onto the page as a user scrolls down. How do I emulate this in my scrapy spiders?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1):

- Inspect the page `(Press F12)` in Google Chrome or similar.
- Click on the `Network` tab.
- Scroll down on the page until you the new data is rendered.
- At the same time the new data is rendered in your browser you should see a new file pop up in the inspection panel.
- The file could be anything depending on the site but most of the time it's JSON.
- Click on the file in inspection panel and copy the `Request URL`.
- Back in scrapy you can send a request to this URL the get the dynamically rendered data.